# Wrapper value extraction using MSXML2.XMLHTTP

Tags: javascript, html, vba, web-scraping, data-extraction

We are currently extracting data from webpage using MSXML2.XMLHTTP.Using my code all data has been extracted except `rvw-cnt-tx` class data.I want to extract 43 Review value from following url.

url="https://www.trendyol.com/lc-waikiki/erkek-cocuk-lacivert-takim-p-78215759?boutiqueId=555784&merchantId=4171"

webpage html:

```html
<a href="/lc-waikiki/erkek-cocuk-lacivert-takim-p-78215759/yorumlar?boutiqueId=555784&amp;merchantId=4171&amp;v=11-12-yas" class="rvw-cnt-tx">43 Reviews </a>
```

My code

```
Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")                                   
http.Open "GET", url, False                                                 
http.Send                                                                   
html.body.innerHTML = http.ResponseText                                     
html1 = html.body.innerHTML                                                 
brand = html.body.innerText                                                 
Dim reviews As String                                                       
cat = html.getElementsByClassName("breadcrumb full-width")(0).innerText     
reviews = html.getElementsByClassName("rvw-cnt-tx")(0).innerText
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is retrieved dynamically. However, you can concatenate `/yorumlar` onto end of your current url to get to the reviews page and there the value is present statically. I use regex to extract the number part of the text where number of reviews is present.

This `html.querySelector(".title h3")` is to restrict regex to searching just the string from a node where that value is present.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetReviewCount()
    'tools > references > Microsoft HTML Object Library
    Dim re As Object, html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument,  xhr As Object

    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    Set xhr = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    re.Pattern = "([0-9,]+)"
    
    With xhr
        .Open "GET", "https://www.trendyol.com/lc-waikiki/erkek-cocuk-lacivert-takim-p-78215759/yorumlar", False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
        .send
        html.body.innerhtml = .responseText
    End With
    Debug.Print re.Execute(html.querySelector(".title h3").innerText)(0).SubMatches(0)
End Sub
```

---

To get your cat variable correctly:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetCat()
    'tools > references > Microsoft HTML Object Library
    Dim html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, xhr As Object

    Set xhr = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    With xhr
        .Open "GET", "https://www.trendyol.com/lc-waikiki/erkek-cocuk-lacivert-takim-p-78215759?boutiqueId=555784&merchantId=4171", False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
        .send
        html.body.innerhtml = .responseText
    End With
    
    Dim nodes As Object, cat As String, i As Long
    
    Set nodes = html.querySelectorAll(".breadcrumb .breadcrumb-item")
    For i = 0 To nodes.Length - 1
        cat = cat & IIf(i = nodes.Length - 1, nodes.Item(i).innerText, nodes.Item(i).innerText & " > ")
    Next
    Debug.Print cat
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks,but count is also available on middle of page having following class pr-rnr-sm-p-s

Comment: html is following <div class="pr-rnr-sm-p-s"><span>42 Reviews </span><div class="seperator"></div><span>29 comments </span></div>

Comment: Hi, You wanted the number of reviews. I have returned the correct number of reviews. I specifically chose the source string I did because it is a shorter string to search therefore more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for clarification,I am using following code for rating extraction but code is not displaying decimal value i.e displaying only 4 not 4.6

Comment: rating = re.Execute(html.getElementsByClassName("pr-rnr-sm-p")(0).innerText)(0)

Comment: thanks no issue resolve after changes in pattern

Comment: Hi ! For ratings alter the character set in the regex `([0-9.]+)` and you can use `html.querySelector(".pr-rnr-sm-p").innerText`

Comment: thank,Is this possible that pattern is also mention in following request http.Open "GET", url, False
    http.Send
      html.body.innerHTML = http.ResponseText
     html1 = html.body.innerHTML

Comment: because above request is not returning > character

Comment: plz check my initial code cat variable is not returning ">" character

Comment: https://www.trendyol.com/lc-waikiki/erkek-cocuk-lacivert-takim-p-78215759?boutiqueId=555784&merchantId=4171

Comment: But on page category is visbile jsut like Home
Kids>
Clothing>
Sets>
LC Waikiki Sets

Comment: What you see on the page, where javascript runs, is not the same as with xhr where there is no javascript running. Open a new question and highlight what value you are after on the page and people can see if we can find where to get that value from.

Comment: still output is without separator  Ana SayfaÇocukAyakkabıEv Botu TerliğiEv Botu

Comment: your above link is not accessible

Comment: Edited answer to address your new question - see bottom part

Comment: still output is same  Ana SayfaÇocukAyakkabıEv Botu TerliğiEv Botu

Comment: Then I assume it is to do with your locale.